Is web browser development only available in QNX SDP 7.0?
I’m interested in testing some QNX Web Browser 2.0 development (https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.blink.browser/topic/browser_about.html). But the Web Browser package is not available for neither SDP 7.1 or 8.0, which is the only versions I have license for.
Is it possible to get the Web Browser package separately in some way? Or do I have to get a 7.0 license and install that locally first?
